# Making a while-loop more scala-esqe

Tags: scala

It is quite clear what the loop below accomplishes.  I somewhat think that it could be made more scala-esque, but I can't quite see it.  I'm posting this to see if anyone has more inspiration than me.

```
  var bunnies: List[Bunny] = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
  var doContinue = true

  while (doContinue) {
    val prevBunnies = bunnies

    bunnies = evolveOneYear(bunnies)

    print(bunnies, prevBunnies)

    if (bunnies.isEmpty) {
      println("\n\n\n  No more bunnies...")
      doContinue = false
    } else {
      println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.\n")
      doContinue = readLine.isEmpty()
    }
  }
```

I wrote this code as an answer to a [codereview post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52483/beginner-project-bunny-city/52530#52530).

**EDIT**:
thanks to @wingedsubmariner and @Kigyo, I have this alternative:

```
  val startBunnies: List[Bunny] = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
  userInputLoop(startBunnies, "")

  @tailrec
  def userInputLoop(bunnies: List[Bunny], userInput: String): Unit = {
    if (userInput.nonEmpty) println("Exiting")
    else evolveOneYear(bunnies) match {
      case Nil => 
        print(Nil, bunnies)
        println("No more bunnies...")
      case newBunnies =>
        print(newBunnies, bunnies)
        userInputLoop(newBunnies, readLine())
    }
  }
```

Or

```
  val startBunnies: List[Bunny] = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
  userInputLoop(startBunnies)

  @tailrec
  def userInputLoop(prevBunnies: List[Bunny]): Unit = {
    evolveOneYear(prevBunnies) match {
      case Nil =>
        print(Nil, prevBunnies)
        println("No more bunnies...")
      case bunnies =>
        print(bunnies, prevBunnies)
        if (readLine().nonEmpty) println("Exiting.")
        else userInputLoop(bunnies)
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 2**:

Another attempt, build from some ideas of Chris Martin and Ben Kovitz:

```
  class NoMoreBunniesException extends Exception("No more bunnies...")
  class UserStoppageException extends Exception("Exiting at your request.")

  def doesUserWantToContinue(): Try[_] = {
    println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.\n");
    if (readLine().isEmpty) Success() else Failure(new UserStoppageException)
  }

  def validateBunnies(bunnies: List[Bunny]): Try[_] = {
    if (bunnies.isEmpty) Failure(new NoMoreBunniesException)
    else Success()
  }

  def checkNotEmptyAndUserContinuation(bunnies: List[Bunny]): Try[_] =
    validateBunnies(bunnies).flatMap(_ => doesUserWantToContinue)

  val firstBunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
  println(s"${buildBunniesReport(firstBunnies).toString}\n\n")

  val timeline = Stream.iterate(firstBunnies)(evolveOneYear)
  val timelineWithPrev = timeline.tail.zip(timeline)
  val statusAndReportTimeline = timelineWithPrev.map {
    case (bunnies, prevBunnies) =>
      (checkNotEmptyAndUserContinuation(bunnies), buildFullReport(bunnies, prevBunnies))
  }

  // main loop including user interaction  
  statusAndReportTimeline.takeWhile {
    case (Success(_), _) => true
    case (Failure(e), report) => { println(s"${report}\n\n${e.getMessage}"); false }
  }.foreach { case (_, report) => println(report) }
```

Comment: This is a really good question because it's a simple and ordinary programming task, yet surprisingly tricky to write without violating at least one principle of idiomatic Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's more functional (perhaps also more abstruse):

```
val firstBunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
val timeline = Stream.iterate(firstBunnies)(evolveOneYear)
val inputLines = Source.fromInputStream(System.in).getLines()

timeline.zip(timeline.tail).iterator
  .takeWhile({ case (previousBunnies, bunnies) => previousBunnies.nonEmpty })
  .zip(Iterator.single("") ++ inputLines)
  .takeWhile({ case (_, input) => input.isEmpty })
  .map({ case ((previousBunnies, bunnies), _) =>
    (bunnies, previousBunnies) + (
      if (bunnies.isEmpty) "No more bunnies..."
      else "Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit."
    )
  })
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: I find the original, procedural version much more readable than this, but it is still very instructive to see the functional version.

Comment: I'd be interested to know from a more experienced functional guru whether using iterators like that is a reasonable practice for reading user input. It feels pretty awkward.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more idiomatic scala by using a tail-recursive function instead of a while loop and eliminiating the vars:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val startBunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)

@tailrec
def loop(prevBunnies: List[Bunny]): Unit = {
  val bunnies = evolveOneYear(prevBunnies)

  print(bunnies, prevBunnies)

  if (bunnies.isEmpty) {
    println("\n\n\n  No more bunnies...")
  } else {
    println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.\n")
    if (readLine.isEmpty)
      loop(bunnies)
  }
}
loop(startBunnies)
```

Comment: You could also pattern match on `evolveOneYear(prevBunnies)` instead of having a `val` and the `if-else`.

Comment: @Kigyo The print call forces us to use a `val`.

Comment: Well, you could have a print for each case in the pattern-match, but I guess it is redundant. You could also integrate the print in the already existing prints for each case. My ego just finds the print for the `Nil`-case not relevant. :)

Comment: Isn't explicit recursion something to avoid except in unusual circumstances? That is, aren't there convenient functional combinators that hide the recursion and let you express the flow more plainly?

Comment: @BenKovitz Avoid if possible, definitely. This is not a place where it can be avoided easily, however. I think the proscription against writing your own tail-recursive methods mostly comes from it not usually being necessary with collections - beginners will write one because they don't understand how general a fold can be.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Separate the functional logic ...
val firstBunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
val timeline = Stream.iterate(firstBunnies)(evolveOneYear)
for ((previousBunnies, bunnies) <- timeline zip timeline.tail) {

  // ... from the I/O.
  print(bunnies, previousBunnies)
  if (bunnies.isEmpty) {
    println("No more bunnies...")
    return
  } else {
    println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.")
  }
  if (readLine().nonEmpty) return
}
```

Comment: Is it idiomatic to break out of a loop with `return`?  Does using the tail with zip recompute the bunnies list at each time step twice?

Comment: 1- No, `return` is generally to be avoided, but IMO that's less important here. 2- No, `Stream` memoizes each step, so bunnies are not recomputed.

Answer (score 1):

The more I consider this, the more I'm bothered by the idea of blocking on the `InputStream` over a human timescale. So here's an approach using Akka!

The setup:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}

// The actor system
val system = ActorSystem()

// The actors: a bunny farm, and a console to interact with it
val farm = system.actorOf(Props[BunnyFarm])
system.actorOf(Props(classOf[BunnyConsole], farm))

// Keep alive until the actor system terminates
system.awaitTermination()
```

The bunny farm:

```
object BunnyFarm {

  // Define the messages that a bunny farm uses
  case object Advance
  case class Result(bunnies: Seq[Bunny], previousBunnies: Seq[Bunny])
}

class BunnyFarm extends Actor {
  import BunnyFarm._

  // A bunny farm's state consists of a list of its bunnies
  var bunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)

  def receive = {

    case Advance =>

      // Advance the state of the farm one year
      val previousBunnies = bunnies
      bunnies = evolveOneYear(bunnies)

      // Reply to the sender with the result
      sender ! Result(bunnies = bunnies, previousBunnies = previousBunnies)
  }
}
```

The console interface:

```
class BunnyConsole(farm: ActorRef) extends Actor with akka.camel.Consumer {

  // Read from stdin
  def endpointUri = "stream:in"

  // Initially advance the farm once
  farm ! BunnyFarm.Advance

  def receive = {
    case m: akka.camel.CamelMessage => self forward m.bodyAs[String]

    // Each string message represents a line of user input
    case s: String => s match {
      case "" => farm ! BunnyFarm.Advance
      case _ => quit()
    }

    // When the bunny farm sends a result...
    case r: BunnyFarm.Result =>

      println(s"Previous bunnies: ${r.previousBunnies}")
      println(s"New bunnies:      ${r.bunnies}")

      if (r.bunnies.nonEmpty) {
        println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.")
      } else {
        println("No more bunnies...")
        quit()
      }
  }

  // Terminate the actor system, thus halting the program
  def quit() = context.system.shutdown()
}
```

Dependencies:

- `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor`
- `com.typesafe.akka:akka-camel`
- `org.apache.camel:camel-stream`

---

**Edit** - The same solution refactored for brevity.

Setup:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}

val system = ActorSystem()
system.actorOf(Props(classOf[BunnyConsole]))
system.awaitTermination()
```

Console:

```
class BunnyConsole extends Actor with akka.camel.Consumer {

  def endpointUri = "stream:in"
  var bunnies = List.fill(nBunniesAtStart)(generateInitialBunny)
  advance()

  def receive = {
    case m: akka.camel.CamelMessage => m.bodyAs[String] match {
      case "" => advance()
      case _ => quit()
    }
  }

  def advance() {
    val previousBunnies = bunnies
    bunnies = evolveOneYear(bunnies)
    print(bunnies, previousBunnies)
    if (bunnies.nonEmpty) {
      println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.")
    } else {
      println("No more bunnies...")
      quit()
    }
  }

  def quit() = context.system.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: Maybe if the rest of the project was using Akka, this would be the best solution, but it is an awful lot longer than the other solutions.

Comment: Some of that length is comments and because I made a separate `BunnyFarm` actor. Updated my answer with another version that makes for a more fair comparison. Especially with the single-actor approach, it doesn't really matter whether the rest of the project involves Akka.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way to do it, aiming for clarity and simplicity.

```
import util.control.Breaks._

val bunniesStream: Stream[List[String]] = firstBunnies #:: bunniesStream.map(evolveOneYear)

breakable {
  for (bunnies <- bunniesStream) {
    println(bunnies)
    if (bunnies.isEmpty) {
      println("No more bunnies...");
      break
    } else {
      println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.\n");
      if (!readLine().isEmpty) break
    }
  }
}
```

The use of `breakable` suggests that this is not idiomatic Scala code.

Comment: There is the same issue as your other post: I need to `print(bunnies, prevBunnies)`.  One of the requirements is to also print out all events such as births and deaths.  (I decided to compute the events after generating the new bunny list, but I could -- and maybe should -- have generated the events list at the same time as the new bunnies list.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another approach. It's horrible. I post it here in the hope that it will inspire someone to re-do its essential idea in a more readable or at least conventional way.

```
val bunniesStream = Stream.iterate(firstBunnies)(evolveOneYear)

case class Interaction(bunnies: List[String]) {
  lazy val print: Unit = println(bunnies)

  lazy val continue: Boolean = {
    print
    if (bunnies.isEmpty) { println("No more bunnies..."); false }
    else userOK
  }

  lazy val userOK: Boolean = {
    println("Hit Enter to continue, or q + Enter to quit.\n");
    readLine().isEmpty
  }
}

bunniesStream.map(Interaction).takeWhile(_.continue).force
```

The idea that I'm trying to implement here is to get the user's input by lazy evaluation. What makes it hard to do the loop in a functional style is the fact that you don't know when to stop the loop until after you've read the user's input, but you might need to stop the loop before reading the user's input.

The last line bundles all the input and output into an expression. Without `.force`, that expression should evaluate to an object which you can then pass to other functions as you like. This seems to follow the spirit of functional programming. No input or output should happen until you do a `.force`. Except it does, because there's something fundamentally wrong with my approach. I don't quite know what it is. Maybe the error has something to do with my mixing decision-making with input/output in the `Interaction` class.

Comment: I think it is not ugly enough: you still have to keep somehow the previous bunnies list fro the function `print(bunnies, prevBunnies)`.

Comment: I had actually thought that printing `prevBunnies` was a mistake, since that was always printed just above the most recent prompt. Printing it might actually make the code a little less ugly, since it's OK to read one generation past the "last" one. I'll fiddle with it.

Comment: By the way, I added an "EDIT 2" in my question where I built another solution attempt using a mix of your ideas (takeWhile) and Chris Martin's ideas (Stream zipped with its own tail).